# Add a source from another file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jpeg

Probably a ridiculously easy question here but I must be phrasing it weird in all of my search queries to find similar solutions.

So in my eclipse project I have a folder with some .jsp files in it. In another folder there are some .jpgs . I want to use one of these .jpg files in my .jsp but for some reason cannot get the classpath correct.

I tried right clicking and copying the qualified name and using that path but it wont link correctly for some reason...

my code looks like :

```
 <img src="pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

I've also tried:

```
 <img src="/My_Project_Name/WebContent/images/pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

Note: the Jsp is in:

```
 /My_Project_Name/WebContent/JSP_FOLDER/JSP.jsp
```

thanks in advance - I know this should be a simple thing...

Comment: In the question it shows it being in `/My_Project_Name/WebContent/images/pikachu.jpg`.

Comment: Have you correctly placed it in web content are you sure it is not in web-inf or some other folder

Comment: The image file is in /My_Project_Name/WebContent/images/pikachu.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Aaron's answer but I believe he has a typo in it (missing an equal sign).

Try this instead, which in my opinion is a little less messy:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

Aaron's solution would have been:

```
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/images/pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

If those don't work, view the page source and copy/paste us what the  line looks like when you are using those.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help - I just had to go in to edit your response to see your code correctly.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that ... forgot to indent the code snippets.   Thanks @dirkk.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
<img src="<%= request.contextPath %>/images/pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

in your JSP.

`<% request.contextPath %>` will expand to the path under which your web server is serving your app.

Every resource inside of `WebContent/` will then be accessible relative to this path.

Related:

- http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-web-application-context-path-in-jsp/

Comment: I like the idea of this but when I try to put it into practice I get:  'Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression'

Comment: @Guenevere: Ah, yes. The `<%` needs to be `<%=`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<img src="../images/pikachu.jpg" height="300" />
```

..(double dots) will move you to parent directory where you are having images folder.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable and simple solution but it does not seem to be working for my case

Comment: can you please post ur project structure here?

Comment: Folder WebContent containing two subFolders - images and jsps, images folder contains the jpg, jsps folder contains the .jsp file